# Заполнение базы данных CodeFirst EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

При создании базы использую для авторизации `Identity`. В файле по умолчанию *IdentityModels.cs* создал класс юзеров ApplicationUser, унаследованный от `IdentityUser` и, собственно, контекст `public class ApplicationUserDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` (всё по гайду).
Далее мне нужна ещё одна сущность `Subject`. Я добавил её как новый класс, и вот незадача: не знаю, как из неё новую таблицу сформировать. Создаю миграцию, но про мой `Subject` в ней ни слова. Я понимаю, что можно дописать вручную, но почему он не добавляется сам?? Конфиг миграции почему-то автоматически закрылся тем контекстом, и про сущность новую как будто не знает: `internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Models.ApplicationUserDbContext>`
Я уже задолбался с этим сидеть, может быть, что-то не так понимаю? Прошу помощи, жду наводящих вопросов, если что-то непонятно написал

Comment: в `ApplicationUserDbContext `
добавили свойство? `public DbSet<Subject> Subjects{ get; set; }`?

Comment: @Andrei, нет.. Если можете, поясните, пожалуйста. Я уже не вкуриваю, голова пухнет от объёма перерытой информации :(

Answer (score 0):

Методом проб и ошибок понял, что нельзя в класс сущности добавлять коллекции типа `DbSet<>`... Стоило заменить на `List<>`, и создалась нужная мне правильная таблица